# ReactJS Error : Only one default export allowed per module

Tags: components

This multiple component doesn't work;

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li><Link>Home</Link></li>
            </ul>

           {this.props.children}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default App;

class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Home...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Home;

ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
      </Route>
   </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'))
```

It give a below error;

> ERROR in ./main.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   C:/Users/hasithay/Desktop/reactApp/main.js: Only one default export
>   allowed per module.
>
> 31 | }   32 |
>
> > 33 | export default Home;
> >          | ^   34 |   35 | class About extends React.Component {   36 |    render() {
>
> @ multi main webpack: bundle is now VALID

Answer should be three clickable links that can be used to change the route When the app is started.

Comment: Well the error tells you exactly what's wrong. You can't have multiple default exports per file. You only need to export stuff if you're importing something in a different file. If you're accessing the component in the same file, there's no need to export anything.

Answer (score 19):

Multiple component does work but you need to export the component with name and you can only export one default component.

Like in below expample I export the **App** Component as defalut component and other component **Home, About, Contact** as a named component.

*For the named component you need to import them using there name :*

**import {Home,About,Contact} from './App.jsx';**

*import default component:*

**import App from './App.jsx';**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <ul>
      <li><Link to="home">Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>

      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;



export class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Home Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}



export class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>About Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}


export class Contact extends React.Component {
  render()  {
    return (
      <h1>Contact Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './App.jsx';
import {Home,About,Contact} from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Contact} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "about" component = {About} />
         <Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
      </Route>
   </Router>

 
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

> Don't import default component (**App** Component) with the name component (**Home, About, Contact**). if you import them with the named component they didn't render properly.
>
> Blockquote

Comment: In case folks are wondering why this doesn't work with React Router v 4.0 they rewrote it. For more information: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732

Answer (score 4):

you have one line with the code:

`export default App;`

After some other lines you have the code:

`export default Home;`

That's just the problem! you have used `export default` 2 times in one file. you have to change one of them to solve the problem.

"you cannot use `export default` more than one time in a file".

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <ul>
      <li><Link to="home">Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>

      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;



export class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Home Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}



export class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>About Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}


export class Contact extends React.Component {
  render()  {
    return (
      <h1>Contact Page Content</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

export all the components in one line

```
export default {App, Home, Contacts, About};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Export Default Home** is used to Expose any module to use in other files, but only one component is a default not all. A module can only be exported once. You are using the same statement to export each component which is unnecessary.

**Importing** components using this statement

`import {Home,About,Contact} from './App.jsx';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `default` keywords on both `App` and `Home` classes, as per code below:

```
export App;
export Home;
```

`default` keywords is only use when you want to export ONE class.